# Create custom dynamic routes with react router and regex to the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a dynamic route with react router for a url that should look something like this

http://localhost:3000/car=honda
http://localhost:3000/bike=yamaha

Both urls should access the same component, however I keep running into some problems.
I don't need any variable from the url itself as I can regex those out myself all I need is for the router to open the component. Here is my implementation

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
     <ProtectedLogin path='/auth' component={Auth}/>
     <Route path={/\/(car|bike)=\w+/} component={Info}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so if there's anyone looking for a solution for something like this, you can create a custom router. Here is my implementation

```
import {Route, Redirect, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import InfoPage from "../../pages/info";

export default function InfoRouter(props) {
    let info = useLocation();
    return (
        <Route {...props} render={props  => {
            if ((/\/(car|bike)=\w+/.test(info.pathname)))
                return <InfoPage/>
            else
                return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}}/>
        }}/>
    )
}
```